# Grep folder within thousands of folders

Tags: regex, search, grep, find, directory

I have a folder filled with approximately 5000 folders.  I want to search within all these folders for folders beginning with numbers i.e. 089781 or 03828 for example.

What kind of regular expression could i use to do this?

Also im on windows and was planning to use the 'grepWin' program.

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Easy on Unix / Cygwin;

```
find . -type d -name '[0-9]*'
```

You can probably find `find` ported to your platform.

That's just a glob, not a regex, btw.